# How to simplify a very large expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
alphan = 1.72*10^(-4); 
alphap = 2.037*10^(-4); 
L = 1.3*10^(-3); 
A = 2.08*10^(-6); 
kp = 1.265; 
kn = 1.011; 
sigmap = 1.314*10^(-5); 
sigman = 1.119*10^(-5); 
alpha = alphap - alphan; 
RTeg =  L/(A)*(sigmap + sigman); KTeg = (A/L)*(kp + kn);

Prhf = 1.45; Prcf = 7; nucf = 10^(-6); nuhf = 0.294*10^(-6); 
Rehf = Vhf*H/nuhf; Recf = Vcf*H/nucf; kcf = 0.5861; khf = 0.6613; 
Nuhf = 0.023*Rehf^(0.8)*Prhf^(0.4); Nucf = 0.023*Recf^(0.8)*Prcf^(0.4);

hhf = Nuhf*khf/H; hcf = Nucf*kcf/H; Lhs = 5*10^(-3); 
Whs = 1.5*10^(-3); Abhs = Lhs*Whs;

rhohf = 965.31; Vhf = 0.0058/(rhohf*Whs*H); mhf = 
rhohf*Vhf*Whs*H; rhocf = 998.21; Vcf = 0.0058/(rhocf*Whs*H); mcf = 
rhocf*Vcf*Whs*H; cph = 4205; cpc = 4153; n = 1;

Thfin = 200 + 273;
Tcfin = 20 + 273;

ZT = 1;    

I1 = alpha*(Th - Tc)/(2*RTeg);

Qh1 = mhf*cph*(Thfin - Thfout);

Qh2 = hhf*Abhs*((Thfin + Thfout)/2 - Th);

Qh3 = alpha*Th*I1 + KTeg*(Th - Tc) - 1/2*I1^2*RTeg;

Qc1 = alpha*Tc*I1 + KTeg*(Th - Tc) + 1/2*I1^2*RTeg;

Qc2 = hcf*Abhs*(Tc - (Tcfin + Tcfout)/2);

Qc3 = mcf*cpc*(Tcfout - Tcfin);

Eq1 = Qh1 == Qh2;

Eq2 = Qc2 == Qc3;

s1 = (Solve[{Eq1, Eq2}, {Thfout, Tcfout}]);

Tcfout = Tcfout /. s1;

Thfout = Thfout /. s1;

Eq3 = Qh1 == Qh3;

Eq4 = Qc1 == Qc3;

s2 = Solve[{Eq3, Eq4}, {Th, Tc}];

Tc = Tc /. s2;

Th = Th /. s2;

eta = (1 - Tc/Th)*(Sqrt[1 + ZT] - 1)/(Sqrt[1 + ZT] + Tc/Th)
Plot[100*eta, {H, 0, 0.002}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.002}, {0, 15}}]
```

This final expression `eta` is in a very complicated form. Is there a way to simplify it further?

I have tried with `Simplify` and `FUllSimplify` but it produces an error.

```
eta = Simplify[(1 - Tc/Th)*(Sqrt[1 + ZT] - 1)/(Sqrt[1 + ZT] + Tc/Th), Assumptions -> {H > 0}]
```

My approach to get an expression `eta(H)` is to use `FindFit`. For this, I first generated data for `eta` vs `H`.

```
data = {{0., 7.74967024886051},
   {0.0001, 7.71700093305254},
   {0.0002, 7.68460139086710},
   {0.0003, 7.65246864300074},
   {0.0004, 7.62059953407060},
   {0.0005, 7.58899075622517},
   {0.0006, 7.55763923443869},
   {0.0007, 7.52654211738270},
   {0.0008, 7.49569582656522},
   {0.0009, 7.46509796431087},
   {0.0010, 7.43474518602558},
   {0.0011, 7.40463462136124},
   {0.0012, 7.37476381266866},
   {0.0013, 7.34512950399817},
   {0.0014, 7.31572913938175},
   {0.0015, 7.28655983779568},
   {0.0016, 7.25761905772651},
   {0.0017, 7.22890432970327},
   {0.0018, 7.20041270773410},
   {0.0019, 7.17214192216995},
   {0.0020, 7.14408919374133}
   };

model1 = b*H + c;
fittingParameter = FindFit[data, {model1}, {b, c}, H]
p3 = Plot[model1 /. fittingParameter, {H, 0, 0.002}];
```

Out[3]= {b -> -302.627, c -> 7.74182}

```
model2 = a*H^2 + b*H + c;
fittingParameter = FindFit[data, {model2}, {a, b, c}, H]
p2 = Plot[model2 /. fittingParameter, {H, 0, 0.002}];
p1 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red];
```

Out[6]= {a -> 12133.4, b -> -326.893, c -> 7.7495}

```
model3 = a*H^3 + b*H^2 + c*H + d;
fittingParameter = FindFit[data, {model3}, {a, b, c, d}, H]
p4 = Plot[model3 /. fittingParameter, {H, 0, 0.002}];
```

Out[10]= {a -> -479488., b -> 13571.9, c -> -328.016, d -> 7.74967}

```
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4]
```

Comment: I assume that you must have tried Simplify, FullSimplify, and their various options? Can you share what you've tried so far and what features of the expression you would like simplified, as well as whether any assumptions can be made in parameters, variables, values?

Comment: @MarcoB I have tried these ways without any luck...

Comment: What error? . . .

Comment: @MichaelE2 `Simplify::infd`

Comment: Is this correct `alpha = 0.2227372967 e - 3;`, `e ` is undefined?

Comment: @DanielHuber You are and I have corrected it...Actually I defined it twice...

Comment: `eta` has  tremendous numbers like `10^126`, can this be correct? If I simplify `eta` I get an expression with numbers like e.g. `10 ^488` and `Indeterminate`. Something with `eta` seems to be fishy.

Comment: @DanielHuber The graphical results seems to be correct...

Comment: The graphics looks good. Can you check if the solution is feasible. Because with such tremendous numbers you could have precision problems. You could also try to do your calculation with exact numbers, provided it does not take too long.

Comment: @DanielHuber The solution is very feasible. I just want a very simple expression if possible for `eta(H)`, which i was able to get through `FindFit`. I am just wondering whether thats the right way to do it?

Comment: If you know a reasonable model, that is fine. Otherwise, you could calculate a few points and then use `Interpolation` to get a function that is fast.